# Qt project structure

Tags: c++, qt, structure, project

I want to structure my project in Qt-Creator like this:

```
MainProject
  main.pro
  SubProject
    sub.pro
    SubSubIncludes
      subsub.pri
```

I tried to achive this by creating the project- and include-files like this:

**main.pro**

```
include(subproject/subproject.pro)
```

**subproject.pro**

```
include(subsubincludes/subsubincludes.pri)
```

What now happens is, that the subsubincludes folder is included to the *MainProject* instead of to the *SubProject* like this:

```
MainProject
  main.pro
  SubSubIncludes // WRONG INCLUDE
      subsub.pri // ALSO WRONG
  SubProject
    sub.pro
```

Comment: Did you use Qt Creator's Subdirs project wizard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by sashoalm I used the Qt Creator's Subdirs project wizard and copied the things I needed.

You can find the Wizard at:

```
"File" -> "New File or Project..." -> "Other Project" -> "Subdirs Project"
```

In the created you can add subprojects by right-click on the .pro file and afterwards click on "New Subproject".

In my case I needed to modify my existing project. Therefore I just had to add/modify the TEMPLATE define in the top-level-project-file(.pro) and the SUBDIRS define like follows:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += NAME_OF_SUBDIR_PROJECT_FOLDER
```